# PL/pgSQL function to test if a word is contained within a phrase

Tags: performance, regex, postgresql, plpgsql

I am using PostgreSQL 11.0 and I wrote a PL/pgSQL function to test if a word or phrase is contained within another phrase. This function is called several times within another function to extract some words from a paragraph. The execution of the calling function is slow, and I suspect it is because of this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."Contains"(
p_text1 character varying,
p_text2 character varying)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
immutable 
AS $BODY$
declare 

v_res integer := 0;

BEGIN

p_text2:= replace(p_text2, '(','\(');
p_text2:= replace(p_text2, ')','\)');

perform 1 
where   ( p_text1 similar to '((% )|(%-)|(%\())*'||p_text2||'(( %)|(-%)|(\)%))*' ) or 
    ( replace(p_text1,'-',' ') similar to '((% )|(%\())*'||replace(p_text2,'-',' ')||'(( %)|(\)%))*' ) or 
    ( replace(p_text1,'-','') similar to '((% )|(%\())*'||replace(p_text2,'-','')||'(( %)|(\)%))*' );      

return found;

END; 
$BODY$;
```

Words (or phrase) boundaries could be spaces (`' word '`), dashes (`'-word-'`), parentheses (`'(word)'`) or nothing (like when the word is at the beginning or the end of the phrase).

For example:

```
select public."Contains"('domain-specific ontology' , 'domain'); -- true
select public."Contains"('domain-specific ontology' , 'ontology'); -- true
select public."Contains"('domain-specific ontology' , 'domain specific'); -- true
select public."Contains"('domain-specific ontology' , 'domain-specific'); -- true
select public."Contains"('information retrieval (IR)' , 'IR'); -- true
select public."Contains"('information retrieval (IR)' , 'information retrieval IR'); -- false
select public."Contains"('domain-specific ontology' , 'domain ontology'); -- false
```

This function is called in the outer function this way:

```
perform 1
         from some_table
         where public."Contains"(col1, v_word) = true;
```

`some_table` has no index on `col1`.

So, is there a faster alternative to the `SIMILAR TO` operator to perform the same regular expression matching?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: can you suggest another title,  please?

Comment: Well, I have only a limited understanding of what you're doing, but perhaps just from the first sentence, "*a PL/pgSQL function to test if a word or phrase is contained within another phrase*" could be a possibility?  (Any question with [tag:performance] is obviously interested in faster alternatives, so it's redundant to mention that in the title, as well as being against site standards)